# Best way to filter an array

Tags: android, listview

What is the best way to filter this array?
The array contain int locations

I tried but I think that I did mistake. Take a look:

```
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView searchList;
    private SearchListAdapter searchListAdapter;

    listContents listC[] = new listContents[]{

            new listContents(R.string.UtrujjTitle,R.string.UtrujjContent,R.drawable.image1),
            new listContents(R.string.AruzzTitle,R.string.AruzzContainer,R.drawable.image2),
            new listContents(R.string.ArzTitle,R.string.ArzContainer,R.drawable.image3)
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        searchList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.searchList);

        searchListAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(this,listC);
        searchList.setAdapter(searchListAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);


        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchable).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                searchListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                List<listContents> listContentses = new ArrayList<listContents>();

                for (int i = 0; i < listC.length; i++) {

                   listContents filterd = listC[i];

                    int title = filterd.getTitleList();
                    int content = filterd.getContentList();

                    if (String.valueOf(title).contains(newText) || String.valueOf(content).contains(newText)) {

                       listContentses.add(filterd);


                    }


                }

                searchListAdapter.setFilter(listContentses);
                searchListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;

            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

The adapter class:

```
    public class SearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<listContents>  {

    private Context context;
    private listContents[] listContentsList;
    private List<listContents> listContentses;

    public SearchListAdapter(Context context, listContents[] listContentses ) {
        super(context,0,listContentses);
        this.context = context;
        this.listContentsList = listContentses;
    }


public void setFilter(List<listContents> lister){
    this.listContentses = lister;
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        listContents listContents = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listresults, parent, false);

        }
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            title.setText(listContents.getTitleList());
           TextView content = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listContain);
           content.setText(listContents.getContentList());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
        imageView.setImageResource(listContents.getImageList());

        return convertView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: all you need is: `searchListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);`, this is what `Filter` is used for

Comment: @pskink I get nothing

Comment: see http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/android-filters-for-simple-listview.html for example

Comment: @pskink Dear I think this way doesn't work anymore on SDK 23

Comment: why shouldn't it? what doesn't work?

Comment: @pskink I put     searchListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); in     onQueryTextChange but nothing show up after adding some texts in search box

Comment: did you try the link i posted? and you say that onQueryTextChange is not called when you type something in the SearchView?

Comment: @pskink Yep I get same response, note that I added Array instead arrayList in adapter

Comment: i have no idea what "response" you are talking about... did you try the example the link i posted? does it work on API 23? if not, what does not work?

Comment: @pskink  Dear, when enter some words in searchview listview will disappear and nothing show up even if I add some words that textviews contain some of them.

Comment: @pskink I don't use String[] , I'm using class array although I convert it to asList in ArrayList but doesn't work either.

Comment: its ok if you dont want to answer my simple question

Comment: @pskink Dear, I answered that I did but nothing show up in listview when enter characters inside search box